# extended Clifford algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, clifford-algebras

I've been implementing real Clifford algebras and have successfully extended the implementation to include basis vectors that square to $1$, $-1$, and $0$ as well as to include a mix of basis vectors that either commute $(uv-vu=0)$ or anticommute $(uv+vu=0)$ with each other.

I have found that the various permutations are real isomorphic to classic real Clifford, complex Clifford, hyperdual numbers, and many other unital associative algebras ($23$ unique algebras in 3D).

Is this still under the name of Clifford algebras, or is there another name for this extension?

Comment: I'm sure the varying signature through $0, \pm 1$ is already subject matter for Clifford algebras.  But allowing basis vectors to commute instead of anticommute is probably not. Discarding that seems to take the algebra properties too far away from its geometric roots.  When all the basis vectors commute you're talking about some quotient of a [symmetric algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra) and if you mix commuting and anticommuting you're probably talking about some chimera of the two.

Comment: So far, I’m thinking it is still generally Clifford but with a more complicated symmetric bilinear form, i.e. uv+vu = zero or 2uv

Comment: Clifford algebras already treat all symmetric bilinear forms, so "more complicated" must mean something that isn't a symmetric bilinear form at all.  Or, the difference lies elsewhere.

Comment: From the abstract to `"Clifford Algebras and their Applications in Mathematical Physics" eds. R Abłamowicz, B. Fauser eds. Birkhäuser Boston 2000, pp. 245-268`:  "Allowing for arbitrary bilinear forms however spoils their diagonalizability which has a considerable effect on the tensor decomposition of the Clifford algebras [...] Theories with non-symmetric bilinear forms are however needed in the analysis of multi-particle states in interacting theories."

Comment: I have also heard that Weyl algebras are the counterparts for Clifford algebras when the form is symplectic. Maybe that's the thread you want to pull on. I don't know if/how they treat degeneracy.

Comment: Well, there it is.  A simpler case of Generalized Clifford Algebra (started by Weyl). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Clifford_algebra ( GCA )

Comment: There's that but those also do not permit (at least in the sense defined there) basis vectors from squaring to $0$.

Comment: little more research showed that basis vectors that square to zero are just a degenerate form of a higher dimensional GCA.  For example, dual numbers are degenerate Cl_1,1.